# trouble with malloc function: Critical error detected c0000374

Tags: sparse-matrix, heap-corruption

I am writing a program about sparse matrices with linked representation.

temp = (matrixPointer*)malloc(sizeof(matrixPointer));

However whenever I use malloc like above for a temporary pointer, it detects an error and stops. It's alright if I have less than 3 inputs, but an error when it becomes 3 or more. Why is this happening? It only says Critical error detected c0000374.

Here is part of my code.

```
for (i = 0; i < numTerms; i++) {
            printf("Enter row, column and value: ");
            scanf("%d%d%d", &row, &col, &value);
            if (row > currentRow) {
                last->right = hdnode[currentRow];
                currentRow = row; last = hdnode[row];
            }
            temp = (matrixPointer*)malloc(sizeof(matrixPointer));
            temp->tag = entry; temp->u.entry.row = row;
            temp->u.entry.col = col;
            temp->u.entry.value = value;
            last->right = temp;
            last = temp;
            hdnode[col]->u.next->down = temp;
            hdnode[col]->u.next = temp;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to [23471161](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471161/critical-error-detected-c0000374-c-dll-returns-pointer-off-allocated-memory). It might help to post more of your code, along with the output of a backtrace from your favorite debugging software.

Comment: I don't know why, but it suddenly started working again when I defined the malloc as a macro. But thank you anyway! I'll read through it to figure out why.